# How to create Excel formula for weight average across two ranges of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to get an Excel weight average across two ranges of cells that are broken apart by some numbers I do not want included and tried the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(AQ6:AQ50,AQ75:AQ256,AT6:AT50,AT75:AT256)/SUM(AT6:AT50,AT75:AT256)
```

But in Excel for Mac v16.12 that gives me a `#VALUE!`, even though either range by itself works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(AQ6:AQ50,AT6:AT50)/SUM(AT6:AT50)
=SUMPRODUCT(AQ75:AQ256,AT75:AT256)/SUM(AT75:AT256)
```

How can I create the weight average across both ranges of cells in a single formula?

Comment: Nothing wrong with you formula it's working I've tested on my sheet. Better you upload the Screen Shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ranges inside the SUMPRODUCT need to be the same size, do two:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(AQ6:AQ50,AT6:AT50)+SUMPRODUCT(AQ75:AQ256,AT75:AT256))/SUM(AT6:AT50,AT75:AT256)
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: In OP's formula, `SUMPRODUCT()` will try to multiply all four arrays together, *then* sum the elements of the resulting array.  That's not what needs to be done, and besides, it throws an error for the reason @ScottCraner mentions.

In plain English, a weighted average is calculated as the sum of the (numbers times their weights), divided by the sum of the weights.  `SUMPRODUCT()` can be used to do that with two arrays of numbers, but it's not as easy to understand what the formula is actually doing.

This array formula gives the correct result:

`=SUM(AQ6:AQ50*AT6:AT50,AQ75:AQ256*AT75:AT256)/SUM(AT6:AT50,AT75:AT256)`

As an array formula, it must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This formula needs some corrections,, it's not working #NA error !!

Comment: @RajeshS this formula works for me if you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter properly.  And you use SUM and not SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: Thanks, @Scott.  I guess I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer, or even comment on it.  I'll come back later. :-)  I wondered why `SUMPRODUCT()` gave an error instead of just a wrong answer.  You explained it.  Good to keep in mind.

Comment: I've used exactly as is written with CSE ! OP's SUMPRODUCT is working nicely.

Comment: It isn't "exactly" or it wouldn't be working correctly.